# Why I can't display/echo -e?

Tags: echo

I am working on a project where I need to pass the value of "-e" meaning "end date" to java program(jar file) but when I tried to debug it by displaying its value(echo) if it's correct or not, the "-e" seems like it doesn't display.

When I tried using other values like "-f", it echoed correctly.

Comment: Yes. but it is all about ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, [here's a verbatim post from U&L](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/168099/338177):

---

- with newline

  ```
   echo -en '-e\n'
  ```
- without newline

  ```
   echo -e '-e\c'
  ```
- with spaces around:

  ```
   echo '-e '
   echo ' -e'
  ```
- using backspace (thanks to Joseph R.):

  ```
   echo -e ' \b-e'
  ```

(it does output SPC BS - e LF, but when sent to a terminal that's rendered as `-e` as BS moves the cursor back one column to the left causing `-` to overwrite the SPC)

The behaviour of `bash`'s `echo` builtin may depend on bash version. It also depends on the environment (`POSIXLY_CORRECT`, `SHELLOPTS` and `BASHOPTS` variables), the options (`posix`, `xpg_echo`), the build options and `argv[0]` (`sh` vs `bash`). Here tested with `GNU bash 4.2.53(1)`, default build, default options, empty environment, invoked as `bash`. Works also with `zsh 5.0.5`.

Comment: Don't bother with `echo` at all: `printf %s -e` (or `printf '%s\n' -e` if you need a trailing new line)

Comment: @muru Indeed, I was thinking to add that to the answer. If you want, edit it adding this advice.

Comment: Thanks everyone! This clarified and answered my question.